# Misunderstood (buggy?) behavior in Read[] function

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

The following expression makes Mathematica invoke Python as a sub-process, have it calculate an arcsine, and returns the result as a real number:

```
(* Test #1 -- Mathematica *)

Read["!python -c \"import math; print '%.30f' % math.asin(0.8)\""]
```

However, this procedure appears to choke on some inputs. For example, if I do ...

```
(* Test #2 -- Mathematica *)

Read["!python -c \"import math; print '%.30f' % math.asin(0.000000000000000000000000000000)\""]
```

... I get an 'EndOfFile', indicating something went wrong.

Just entering the following on the shell command line works fine:

```
$ # Test #3 -- bash

$ python -c "import math; print '% .30f' % math.asin(0.000000000000000000000000000000)"
   0.000000000000000000000000000000
```

I don't understand what goes wrong in Test #2. The issue appears to be quite sensitive to the number of zeroes I put in the "0.00000...".

I am using Mathematica 9.0.1 in Linux.

Can anyone explain Mathematica's behavior in test #2?

Comment: I don't know mathematica, but does the output variable's length/precision setting change things?

Comment: I suggest deleting this post and asking your question on [Mathematica.SE](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com).  I think this may be related to (if not outright caused by) a but that was reported recently.  See [this Chat section](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/12693825#12693825) and the comments under the post it links to.  Apparently in v9 `Read` and `ReadList` don't handle long numbers correctly.

Comment: try Read[, String] to see if thats whats going on.  Read[, Expression] might work for  you as well

Comment: one other thing to be aware of, Read["!command"] leaves its input stream open *even if the external command immediately exits*. If you repeat the *exact same* command, instead of running a new shell process it tries to read from the first one and you get an EndOfFile error.  You should be sure to close the stream with Close["!command"]